# The Color behind my custom shape is filled and I want to make it white

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibezierpath

Essentially the picture shows it, but the gray background behind the orange shape I want to make make transparent and/or white(or any color frankly). I'm just wondering where can I change the color of the shape's background and whats the syntax for it.    [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMpYz.png)

```
class DemoView: UIView {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    var path: UIBezierPath!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func createRectangle() {
        path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0.0, y: 0.0))

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 300.0))

        //path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height))


        //self.frame.size.height
        path.addCurve(to:CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: 300.0), controlPoint1:  CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: 400), controlPoint2:  CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: 400))

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: 0.0))

        path.close()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.createRectangle()

        UIColor.orange.setFill()
        path.fill()

        UIColor.purple.setStroke()
        path.stroke()


    }
}
```

in the view controller below

```
let height: CGFloat = 400.0

               let demoView = DemoView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                                     y: self.view.frame.size.height/2 - height/2,
                                                     width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                     height: height))

               self.view.addSubview(demoView)
```

Comment: also how can i make the color of the shape an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it by changing demo view background color

```
let demoView = DemoView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                            y: self.view.frame.size.height/2 - height/2,
                                            width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                                            height: height))
      demoView.backgroundColor = .green
      self.view.addSubview(demoView)
```

Also you can change it in your DemoView `init` method

```
  class DemoView: UIView {

    var path: UIBezierPath!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

       // self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.backgroundColor = // Any color you want or clear color
    }
```

[image]

Comment: ok awesome thank you so much. I just have one quick more question. How can I change the color of the orange to an image?

Comment: you can do it like this ...
 `UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "rw-logo")!).setFill()` instead of `UIColor.orange.setFill()`